# React-virtualized List selected item styling only fire when scroll up

Tags: reactjs, react-virtualized

I'm using React-virtualized to show the data as list. 
I add selected styling for list item, it supposes highlight the item once it got click.
The current problem is `onClick` is fired, but selcted styling only shows when scroll up the list.

`List component`

```
 <div className={styles.autoSizerContainer}>
                <AutoSizer>
                    {({width, height}) => {
                        // Selected customer styling only fire after scroll
                        return (
                            <List
                                width={width}
                                height={height}
                                rowHeight={50}  
                                rowRenderer={this.renderRow}
                                rowCount={rowCount}
                                overscanRowCount={3}    
                                className={styles.list}
                            />
                        )
                    }}
                </AutoSizer>
            </div>
```

`List item`

```
private renderRow = ({index, key, style}: ListRowProps) => {
        const data = this.props.dataList[index];
        return (
            <div style={style} key={data.id}>
                <div className={styles.listItem}>
                    <div>data.name</div>
                    <Item key={data.id} 
                         isDataSelected={this.state.selectedId === data.id}
                    /> //return true will show selected styling
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    };
```

`"react-virtualized": "^9.21.0",`

`"react": "^16.8.4"`

Any ideas are welcome!

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React-Virtualized will only re-render your component when one of the props provided by ListRowProps changes.  It doesn't know that your render method uses `this.props.dataList` and `this.state.selectedId` internally.  You will need to do one of two things.

1. Explicitly tell the List to redraw when `this.state.selectedId` changes.  The List exposes an api for this purpose.
2. Use something like React's Context api to provide the necessary data in a way such that changes can be detected.  Something like this should work:

```
const {Provider, Consumer} = React.createContext<number | null>(null);
```

```
 <div className={styles.autoSizerContainer}>
                <AutoSizer>
                    {({width, height}) => {
                        // Selected customer styling only fire after scroll
                        return (
                            <Provider value={this.state.selectedId}>
                            <List
                                width={width}
                                height={height}
                                rowHeight={50}  
                                rowRenderer={this.renderRow}
                                rowCount={rowCount}
                                overscanRowCount={3}    
                                className={styles.list}
                            />
                            </Provider>
                        )
                    }}
                </AutoSizer>
            </div>
```

```
private renderRow = ({index, key, style}: ListRowProps) => {
        const data = this.props.dataList[index];
        return (
            <Consumer>
            {(selectedId) =>
            <div style={style} key={data.id}>
                <div className={styles.listItem}>
                    <div>data.name</div>
                    <Item key={data.id} 
                         isDataSelected={selectedId === data.id}
                    /> //return true will show selected styling
                </div>
            </div>
            }
            </Consumer>
        )
    };
```

Comment: It's quite awkward, I figured out as long as i change this component to FunctionalComponent, it works fine, but written with class component the selected color shows only scroll up the list....... anyway it solved. Thanks again